# Fast access to excel data in X++

Tags: excel, office-interop, axapta, x++

Can someone give me a clue how can I get the fast access of the excel data. Currently the excel contains more than 200K records and when I retrieve from the X++ code it takes a lot of time to retrieve all the records.

Following are the classes I am using to retrieve the data.
1 - SysExcelApplication, SysExcelWorksheet and SysExcelCells.

I am using the below code to retrieve cells.

```
excelApp.workbooks().open(filename);
excelWorksheet  = excelApp.worksheets().itemFromName(itemName);
excelCells      = excelWorkSheet.cells();
///pseudo code
loop
    excelCells.item(rowcounter, column1);
    similar for all columns;
end of loop
```

If any of the special property needs to be set here please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall performance will be a lot better (huge!) if you can use **CSV files**. If you are forced to use Excel files, you can easy and straigforward **convert this excel** file to a csv file and then read the csv file. If you can't work that way, you can read excel files throug **ODBC** (using a query string like connecting to a database) that will perform better that the Office API.

Comment: Yes ODBC is better option because we can't convert excel file into CSV. All the things need to be done via X++.

Comment: Good to be helpful. If you have time comparision of the process using different technologies it would be nice to know. On my own experience, from Office Interop to ODBC or CSV the change is from many hours to some seconds/minutes.

Answer (score 0):

First things, reading Excel files (and any other file) will take a while for 200 K records.

You can read an Excel file using [ExcelIo](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=ExcelIo), but with no performance guaranties :)

As I see it, you have 3 options (best performance listed first):

1. Convert your Excel file to CSV file, then read with [CommaIo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/commaio.aspx).
2. Read the Excel file using C#, then call back to X++
3. Accept the fact and take the time

Comment: You could make Excel save to disk as CSV by code.
But I have never done that!

Answer (score 0):

use CSV, it is faster, below is code example:

```
     /* Excel Import*/
#AviFiles

#define.CurrentVersion(1)
#define.Version1(1)
#localmacro.CurrentList
#endmacro

FilenameOpen    filename;

CommaIo         file;
Container       con;

/* File Open Dialog */
Dialog  dialog;
dialogField dialogFilename;
dialogField dialogSiteID;
dialogField dialogLocationId;
DialogButton dialogButton;
InventSite objInventSite;
InventLocation objInventLocation;
InventSiteID objInventSiteID;
InventLocationId objInventLocationID;
int row;
str sSite;
NoYes IsCountingFound;
int iQty;
Counter insertCounter;
Price itemPrice;
ItemId _itemid;
EcoResItemColorName _inventColorID;
EcoResItemSizeName _inventSizeID;


dialog              =   new Dialog("Please select file");
dialogSiteID        =   dialog.addField(extendedTypeStr(InventSiteId), objInventSiteId);
dialogLocationId    =   dialog.addField(extendedTypeStr(InventLocationId), objInventLocationId);
dialogFilename      =   dialog.addField(extendedTypeStr(FilenameOpen));

dialog.filenameLookupFilter(["@SYS100852","*.csv"]);
dialog.filenameLookupTitle("Please select file");
dialog.caption("Please select file");
dialogFilename.value(filename);

if(!dialog.run())
return;

objInventSiteID = dialogSiteID.value();
objInventLocationID = dialogLocationId.value();

/*----- validating warehouse*/
while
select maxof(InventSiteId) from objInventLocation where objInventLocation.InventLocationId == objInventLocationId
{
    If(objInventLocation.InventSiteID != objInventSiteID)
    {
        warning("Warehouse not belongs to site. Please select valid warehouse." ,"Counting lines import utility");
        return;
    }
}

filename  =   dialogFilename.value();
file = new commaIo(filename,'r');
file.inFieldDelimiter(',');

try
{

    if (file)
    {
        ttsbegin;
        while(file.status() == IO_Status::OK)
        {

           con = file.read();

            if (con)
            {
                row ++;

                if(row == 1)
                {
                    if(
                       strUpr(strLtrim(strRtrim( conpeek(con,1) ))) != "ITEM"
                    || strUpr(strLtrim(strRtrim( conpeek(con,2) ))) != "COLOR"
                    || strUpr(strLtrim(strRtrim( conpeek(con,3) ))) != "SIZE"
                    || strUpr(strLtrim(strRtrim( conpeek(con,4) ))) != "PRICE"
                    )
                    {
                        error("Imported file is not according to given format.");
                        ttsabort;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {


                    IsCountingFound = NoYes::No;
                    _itemid = "";
                    _inventColorID = "";
                    _inventSizeID = "";


                    _itemid = strLtrim(strRtrim(conpeek(con,1) ));
                    _inventColorID = strLtrim(strRtrim(conpeek(con,2) ));
                    _inventSizeID = strLtrim(strRtrim(conpeek(con,3) ));
                    itemPrice = any2real(strLtrim(strRtrim(conpeek(con,4) )));

                }
           }
         }

         if(row <= 1)
         {
            ttsabort;
            warning("No data found in excel file");
         }
         else
         {
            ttscommit;

         }
    }
 }
catch
{
    ttsabort;
    Error('Upload Failed');
}
```

Comment: Can we convert excel file to csv using X++? and If I convert it, i assume it will take time.

Comment: Export to CSV from within Excel.  See section.  "Export data to a text file by saving it"
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx

Comment: Performance gain will be huge (exponentially) for big files. Importing 200K rows with excel interops will long for hours and importing CSV will run in seconds.